# dplyr Replace specific cases in a column based on row conditions, leaving the other cases untouched

Tags: r, dplyr, replace

How can I apply, two (or more) replace cases, in a column based on rows from another column? For example, giving the next data frame

```
data <- data.frame(x1 = c(1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2),  
                     x2 = c(4, 36, 45, 22, 36, 1, 11, 12, 31, 22))
```

I want to apply 2 conditions:

- If X1 = 1 then replace its corresponding value in X2 by YES
- If X1 = 2 then replace its corresponding value in X2 by NO
- Leave all the other values unchanged, keep the original values in X2

I wanted to use the "replace" function with "case_when" for this but I did not find a solution. I used then the "mutate" option, but it replaced the values I wanted to leave untouched by NAs.
(I want to use case_when or similar to optimize my script, here I just provide an example but I may need to substitute many cases and I do not want to have multiple times the "replace" function in my pipe :) )

I used the next:

```
data %>%
  mutate(x2 = case_when(x1 %in% 1 ~   “YES”,
                        x1 %in% 2 ~   “NO”))
```

And what I obtained:

[image]

How can I solve this? Thank you in advance

S

Answer (score 5):

You almost had it.

For rows where you have no condition and you want to leave as is, you can do:

```
data %>%
  mutate(x2 = case_when(x1 %in% 1 ~ 'YES',
                        x1 %in% 2 ~ 'NO',
                        TRUE ~ as.character (x2)))


   x1  x2
1   1 YES
2   2  NO
3   3  45
4   2  NO
5   4  36
6   1 YES
7   2  NO
8   3  12
9   4  31
10  2  NO
```

Comment: Just note that the column ´x2` won't be numeric after this. In particular the last line should be `TRUE ~ as.character(x2)` or otherwise you get an error.

Comment: Yep, I forgot that part. Also the quotation marks grom the TOs code aren‘t valid, it seems, so I will replace them as well.

Answer (score 1):

A base R option using `match` + `replace`

```
transform(
  data,
  x2 = {
    v <- c("yes", "no")[match(x1, c(1, 2))]
    replace(data$x2, !is.na(v), na.omit(v))
  }
)
```

gives

```
   x1  x2
1   1 yes
2   2  no
3   3  45
4   2  no
5   4  36
6   1 yes
7   2  no
8   3  12
9   4  31
10  2  no
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more 'fun' approach with nested `ifelse`. The presented answers by @deschen and @ThomasIsCoding are my favorites:

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  mutate(x2 = ifelse(x1 > 2, x2,
                         ifelse(x1==2, "NO", 
                                ifelse(x1 ==1, "YES", x2))))
```

```
   x1  x2
1   1 YES
2   2  NO
3   3  45
4   2  NO
5   4  36
6   1 YES
7   2  NO
8   3  12
9   4  31
10  2  NO
```

Comment: the nested `ifelse` is really fun, cheers!